# Handling dates with different precision and a wide time span in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date

I would like to know how to handle and store dates like birthdates in Ruby on Rails when the exact day or month might be unknown and some birthdates are BC.

MySQL seems to support dates like "1990-00-00", which could be used to store the year without month and day, but BC dates don't seem to be possible. Since MySQL supports dates until the year 9999 and I need only birthdates up to today, the higher dates could be used to represent BC dates (9999 = -1, 9998 = -2, ...), but this seems complicated and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Postgresql? LOL, just kidding. There are some solutions out there that suggest adding a constant to ALL dates in the background then subtracting it before display. Seems messy. Rails doesn't care how long ago your date is though. So you could store those dates as strings like '2023-01-29' or '-5000-01-29' and then parse them in rails:

```
Date.parse('29 Jan 2023')
=> Sun, 29 Jan 2023

Date.parse('-5000-01-29')
=> Fri, 29 Jan -5000

Date.parse('29 Sep 1000 BC')
=> Sun, 29 Sep -0999
```

As you can see Rails handles dates quite well and can parse a number of different string formats into dates. You could override the setter/getter for the column in the model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # "Uses a string to hold the date for the column 'bar'"

  def bar=(date)
    super(date.to_s)
  end

  def bar
    Date.parse(super)
  end
end
```

Now when you have an instance of Foo and call `.bar` it will get converted from the string in the DB to a date, and when given a date in the setter method it will convert it to a string for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not able to find any solutions in the web, making me wonder if I was the only person with this problem. Could you point me to some solutions or name the correct keywords for a web search?

Comment: I used "mysql dates before AD" and found things like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/best-way-to-handle-dates-prior-to-1000-a-d-in-mysql

Comment: Is my answer not what you were looking for? There is no "fix" from what I've found. Even PostgreSQL only covers "4713 BC to 5874897 AD". You can do all sorts of gyrations with storing dates as integers and then converting like the link above. But why not just store it in a nice human readable string as suggested and then let Rails do the work? Yes, there could be some issues with sorting, but I think the fix for that would be adding something like a "date_order" column that take the Date and converts it with `.to_time.to_i` so you get an integer. You can then use that column for sorting.

Comment: It is just that I already have a db with 10,000s of dates. So I might run into performance (and other) issues. Since MySQL has a date type and this is already being used, I thought it might be possible to keep it.

Comment: Then you will have to resort to some sort of "offset" type scheme. That is probably the only way you are going to use your current column, and you'd still need to update them. If I was tasked with this I would add two columns to the DB, one for the string date, one for the integer for sorting. Performance for sorting should be fast on an integer column. You would be able to test the rails code for display without touching your current column of dates.

Comment: During low utilization you could have Rails insert into the new string date column with a date based on current Date column. Not sure how performance is impacted due to the number of existing rows. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I also have to keep in mind that especially for BC for some birthdays only the decade or even century is known and MySQL functions like year() would not work anymore. So I might need to make further adjustments.

Comment: You have a lot of flexibility with overriding the default column name as I showed above. I gave the example of just translating from date to string and in reverse. But you can expand that as much as you want. You could add some `if... else` or `case` statements to handle different situations. If the string is 4 digits long or less you could store just the string of '-1000' and then when you retrieve it with the getter method you could just to a `.to_i` on it to get an integer year.